# Size of array in C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

Consider the following code:

```
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,7,8};
    int size = sizeof(arr);
    cout << size;
}
```

I know that the above code will print the size of the array which is 4*5 = 20 bytes but i have a small doubt in this, `arr` is a pointer to the first element in the array and the size of a ptr variable is 4 bytes so why it does not print out 4 in the console?

Even when we dereference `arr` and print it, the first element in the array will be printed.

```
cout << *arr;
```

So how does this `sizeof()` operator work in case of arrays??

Comment: Arrays and pointers are not the same thing. Sometimes they are confused because arrays very easily turn into pointers to their first element. But this hasn't happens here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This is a nice question now. Have an upvote!

Comment: "*`arr` is a pointer to the first element in the array*" - no, it is not.  But it does *decay* into such a pointer, if `arr` is used in a context where a pointer is expected. Whic his not the case in this example, so `sizeof()` sees the entire array, not just a pointer to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(arr)` is one of those instances where `arr` does *not* decay to a pointer type.

You can force pointer decay by using the unary plus operator:

```
std::size_t/*a better type*/ size = sizeof(+arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

> `arr` is a pointer to the first element in the array

This is a wrong assumption. `arr` is **not** a pointer. It is an array of 5 integers.

> so why it does not print out 4 in the console?

Because that is not the size of `arr` in bytes.

> So how does this sizeof() operator work in case of arrays??

You get the size of the type in bytes. Same as every other type.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answers you can also get the number of elements using C++11's [std::extent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent)

On my machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,7,8};

  std::cout << sizeof(arr) << "\n";
  std::cout << sizeof(+arr) << "\n";
  std::cout << std::extent<decltype(arr)>::value << "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
20
8
5
```

---

From @eerorika comment:

If you use C++17 you can also use [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size)

```
std::cout << std::size(arr); // prints 5
```

Comment: To get the size of the array in elements: `std::size(arr)`

Comment: @eerorika Thank you, I did not know this one! (just checked it, also it is c++17).

Comment: std::extent is better (more general) as it is constexpr and can be used with arrays embedded in structs when you do not have an instance.